# get json object with jquery

Tags: jquery, json, getjson, jsonresult

```
$.getJSON("<%: Url.Action("myUrl", "cont") %>/", function(data) {
        var items = [];
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            items.push(val);
        });
     });

    [Authorize]
    [OutputCache(Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")]
    public JsonResult myUrl()
    {
        var list = _repository.GetAll();
        var items = list.Select(c => c.Name).ToList();

        return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I create a list on the server side (list of string names) and return a JsonResult. I'm trying to get the list on the client side using jquery so i can check if it contains a particular item. The above doesnt seem to work...any suggestions?

Comment: Is not data a JSON Object? I think you can use it as you desire.

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the JSON:

```
$.get("<%: Url.Action("myUrl", "cont") %>/", function(data) {
    var items = [];
    data = $.parseJSON(data);
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        items.push(val);
    });
 });
```

Comment: Sorry, havent seen `getJSON`. Maybe try my current method. If you are using POST instead of GET, modify it. With this you can `alert(data)` before it gets processed by `$.parseJSON`.

Comment: i've tried your method, it's still null, i know for sure that the JSonResult returned by the server has items in it

Comment: Then please add an `alert(data);` just after `var items = [];` and tell me what it outputs.

Comment: ok, it's odd, but it appears to work now. Data has my list i..e item1,item2,item3...i've moved the var items = [] out of the json, but when it exits the getJSON, items seems to lose its value and is null....not sure why this would happen?

Comment: @newbie_86 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1831/discussion-between-marc-and-newbie-86)