# jQuery Ajax: set scope of json object to parent function

Tags: jquery, scope

I'm trying to set the returned object from a jQuery Ajax call to the scope of the parent function (jQuery Ready).
I'm probably missing something obvious, but I'm pretty tired today and I can't find it.
In comment, I gave some feedback on the console.logs.

Here is my current code:

```
$(function () {
    var json_contracts; 
    var parent_id = $('#dropdown_parents').select2('data').id;         
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET', 
        url: 'http://www.ingemployeebenefits.com/develop_kgy/entities/parents/db_parents_getcontracts.php',
        dataType: 'json', 
        data: {
            'parent_id': parent_id
        },
        success: function(data) {
            json_contracts = data;
            //This line returns the object properly 
            console.log(json_contracts); 
        }, 
        error: function (xhr,status,error) {
                   $('#msg_parent_view').html("Error: " + error);
                   return false;
                }
    });
    //This line returns undefined. 
    console.log(json_contracts); 
});
```

I also checked out this post: [Set javascript global variable to JSONresult?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830283/set-javascript-global-variable-to-jsonresult)

I can't see what I'm doing diffferently.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic AJAX, your global variable is being assigned but your `console.log` statement returns `undefined` because it is hit before your AJAX is complete. Either do your logic inside the `success` function or pass in a callback function which takes your `data` as a parameter.

Comment: Right that's it obviously. Thanks, I'll accept in a few mins

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because `console.log()` is called before ajax call is completed.

Add callback and it should work.

Try:

```
$(function () {
    var json_contracts; 
    var parent_id = $('#dropdown_parents').select2('data').id;    
    function get_value(function(){
        console.log(json_contracts);
    });
    function get_value(callback){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET', 
            url: 'http://www.ingemployeebenefits.com/develop_kgy/entities/parents/db_parents_getcontracts.php',
            dataType: 'json', 
            data: {
            'parent_id': parent_id
            },
            success: function(data) {
                json_contracts = data;
                console.log(json_contracts); 
        }, 
           error: function (xhr,status,error) {
                   $('#msg_parent_view').html("Error: " + error);
                   return false;
                }
        });
    }        
});
```

Comment: Cool, I upvoted your answer but got it already figured out; I will accept tymeJV's answer as he was first. Thanks